# htaccess still loading the last edition

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^content/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?:/|$) content.php?contentid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and when I try to refresh the address:

```
localhost/projects/something/php/content/
```

it shows me the last result! I deleted the line in htaccess! I tried to clear the htaccess file but still shows me the page!

System Info:
Wamp 3.0.6 64bit
Win10
Firefox latest

Comment: `localhost/projects/something/php/content/testid` same result

Comment: That regex doesn't match that path.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my htaccess is clear! no code in there but still loading some pages!

Comment: @magnus-eriksson works fine in server but on local i have this problem!
and how to fix the path?! please explain more

Comment: The regex pattern `^content/` marches strings that _starts_ with `content/`. (`^` = start of string). Your uri starts with: `projects/`, not `content/`. Do you have the site in a sub folder locally and in the root on the server? Or is the path `project/something/php/content` on your server as well?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson path of htaccess and site in local is
`project/something/php/`
I have no problem with this code! works fine with my other projects! but sometimes like now it happens! htaccess is working like it is cached or something!

Comment: Have you restarted the webserver? You also need to elaborate a bit. What line have you deleted? What is the "last result" you're seeing? Basically, tell us what the expected result should be and what result you're actually getting (with a bit more info than "the last result" which doesn't mean anything to us). You should also include your complete htaccess.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes web server restarted many times!
I deleted All lines from htaccess. the file is empty but some urls still working!! like there is a cached htaccess in apache! result is not error! result is that i dont get the GET parameeters 'contentid=$1'.
maybe my apache need to reinstall!

Comment: Do you have a htaccess in any of the parent folders?

Comment: Problem is with Apache and Windows!